# post data from jquery to php

Tags: php, jquery

My code creates dynamic input text through jquery and sends data to php (and after to my db).
Creations are fine but PHP doesn't receive the text of the input.
I tried with $.post() and $.ajax() but probably I used these methods badly.

Inputs:

```
...
<script>
var i=0;


$( "#btnTag" ).on( "click", function() {
$( this ).after( '<p> Tipo Tag: <select name="tipoTag'+i+'"><option        value="ricerca">Ricerca</option><option value="classificazione">Classificazione</option> <option value="processo">Processo</option><option value="organizzative_interne">Organnizzative Interne</option></select>Nome Tag:<input type="text" id="txtTag'+i+'" name="txtTag'+i+'"/></td><td><input type="reset"  value="Rimuovi" id="btnDel" name="btnDel"/></p> ' );
$("#btnDel").on("click",function() {
$(this).parents('p').remove();  i--;});

i++;
});

</script>
...
```

In the php file:

```
//connection...
$count=0;
while(true){
if(isset($_POST['"txtTag'.$count+"'"])){
$nomeTag=$_POST["'txtTag".$count."'"];
$tipoTag=$_POST['"tipoTag'.$count.'"'];
$count++;
continue;
}else break;
}
```

Error: Undefined index for txtTag0 and tipoTag0

Comment: It looks a little bit senseless this way, but everytime I receive these data I'll make a insert query

Comment: the inconsistency of this code hurts my brain...

Comment: if it's not isset it breaks -.-

Comment: Yeh..that's fine..realized it later that `$count` is being incremented. Also you won't need `continue` inside the loop. It will automatically iterate for the next item.

Comment: Thank you evewrybody! I'm sorry for my stupid errors but I have been working with PHP for a short time

Answer (score 0):

You have too many quotes in your PHP $_POST indexes. It should be like this

```
$_POST['txtTag' . $count]
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
//connection...
$count=0;
while(true){
    if(isset($_POST['txtTag'.$count])){
        $nomeTag=$_POST['txtTag'.$count];
        $tipoTag=$_POST['tipoTag'.$count];
        $count++;
        continue;
    }else{
       break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try with JQuery Documentation about Ajax Functions [JqueryApi](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/)

Comment: More of a comment than an answer

Answer (score 0):

Better to use array of elements like,

```
<select name="tipoTag[]">...<input type="text" name="txtTag[]"/>
```

And in **PHP** use it like,

```
if(isset($_POST['tipoTag']) and !empty($_POST['tipoTag'])) {
    // no need to make an infinte loop
    foreach($_POST['tipoTag'] as $key => $tipotag){
        echo $txttag=isset($_POST['txtTag'][$key]) ? $_POST['txtTag'][$key] : '';
        echo $tipotag;
    }
}
```

Also don't use `+` for concatenation in **PHP**